# Access denied while changing ContentTypeId

Tags: development, permissions, csom, content-type, access-denied

I got an error when I have **Contribute** permission for site:

> Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource.

my code is uploading the file and then trying to change content type of that file, uploading code works fine, but changing content type throws an exception.

Here is the code I am using:

```
var file = context.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(serverRelativeUrl);
context.Load(file);
context.ExecuteQuery(); // excuted fine 

file.ListItemAllFields["ContentTypeId"] = attachment.CType.Id;
file.ListItemAllFields.Update();
file.ListItemAllFields.SystemUpdate();
file.Update();
context.Load(file);
context.ExecuteQuery(); // Exception here
```

any idea for solving this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing SystemUpdate, you need SiteCollection Administrator Permissions here.